# Error using fastlane (Google Api Error: apkSignedWithDifferentCertificate)

Tags: android, apk, fastlane

I'm trying to use Fastlane to upload APKs to Google Play but I am getting this **error**:

> Google Api Error: apkSignedWithDifferentCertificate: APK has been
>   signed with a different certificate to previous APKs.

However, I upload the APK manually and I don't get any error. I'm always using the same certificate to sign and the details are in my **build.gradle**.

Any ideas what could be happening? My lane is very simple:

lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "assembleRelease")
    supply
  end

Comment: same happens to me, manually adding the same file is accepted. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

can you check if you have any wrong/outdated `.apk` files in your project folder that supply falsly takes?

or even better set the apk path in supply using the  `apk` option?
for a detailed list of all supply options run

`fastlane action supply`

or have a look at the online documentation here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#supply